# TeX Live 2010 or 2011 in 11.10?

Tags: package-management, 11.10, latex

Will Ubuntu 11.10 ship with TeX Live 2010 or 2011? [It seems Debian will](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) [package TeX Live 2011](http://osdir.com/ml/debian-tex-maint-debian/2011-05/msg00041.html) and TeX Live 2011 has now been released.

See also: needs-packaging request on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521).

Comment: Even after debian packages it it will take some time to filter into ubuntu. May I suggest you install directly from TUG instead? That way you are not dependent on distro packaging practices for TeX packages which change pretty fast.

Comment: @Jasper Loy That is a good suggestion. There is [a good question on tex.sx about that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/5701). However it is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Right, hence I put it as a comment. See you around!

Comment: I opened a bug on this back in February https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521. Feel free to mark yourself as affected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it [appears](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base) that Ubuntu 11.10 will still have TeX Live 2009, rather than either 2010 or 2011. As Ingo Gerth says, you can subscribe to [bug 712521](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521) and use the green "This bug affects..." link near the top of that bug page, to indicate that you are affected by this.

Comment: At least it seems that [11.10 will include biblatex 1.4c](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/biblatex) (instead of 11.04's 0.9a). Also it seems that [11.10 will include luatex 0.70.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/luatex) (instead of 11.04's 0.65.0).

Answer (score 0):

It is now more than a year since Ubuntu 11.10 was released. The upgrade from TeX Live 2009 [came first with Ubuntu 12.10 which includes TeX Live 2012](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/texlive).

Still I have found that it easier to keep TeX Live up to date [by installing it directly from upstream](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1094/5701).