# Does anyone know why does Ubuntu 11.10 use TeXLive 2009?

Tags: compatibility, versions, latex

Many of my old examples for PGF plots do not work any more. I think the problem is due to this. Does anyone know why 11.10 use the old version of TeXLive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, the main reason is that no one did the work to package TeXLive 2010 and 2011 for Debian/Ubuntu.

See [Ubuntu Bug #712521: [Needs packaging] TeXLive 2011](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521) (especially the comments) for some background information.

The current advice (from the TeX community) is to [install TeXLive 2011 yourself](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), either instead or additionally to the TeXLive 2009 from Ubuntu.

Comment: See the comments at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/712521 for details. Also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/48030/tex-live-2010-or-2011-in-11-10 might be interesting on these matters.

Comment: I really regretted to update to Ubuntu 11.10. Since then, I have had so many problems with my system.

Comment: @Anand Ubuntu 11.10 has the same TeX Live version as the former. If you want a more recent version of TeX Live I suggest you install directly from TUG, it's not hard, see http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: @N.N. Thanks, I added these links to the answer.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann and N.N. thank you very much. My problem has finally been solved. It is not the problem of TeXlive 2009. Please see this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32776/2364